# Create a starting point for an autosum feature other than zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an auto sum cell that currently starts at 0. The cells I am summing are input boxes, but there are also static boxes in the list. I would like to either include the static boxes in the auto sum feature, or create an alternative starting point other than 0. here is my current code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $('.budget').each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $('.budget').each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#total").html(sum.toFixed(0));
}
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what's stopping you from doing this. Also, I see no java here.

Comment: You realize Java and Javascript are two completely unrelated things right?

Comment: Please remove the `java` tag from your question. Read this page for more information on creating a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about passing in the initial value to the function:

```
function calculateSum(params) {
  var sum = params && params.init || 0;
  ...
}

calculateSum({ init: 12 });
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mbe9hr48/)